# How to remove space in graphics using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to remove some space in my plot, but when I use `ylim` I got the following warning:
`Warning message: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text).`
Then I lost some data.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data_se5) +
  geom_bar(data=data_se5, aes(x = SEM_PRI, y = acumobito,#color = "Número de internações acumuladas", 
                              fill = CLASSI_FIN,
                              group=CLASSI_FIN),color="transparent",stat="identity") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=20), legend.position="none") +   #re
    annotate("text", x = 1:25, y=cumsum(aggregate(obito ~ SEM_PRI, dadoscovid2, sum)$obito) + 2, 
          vjust = -.8, label = sort(data_se5[data_se5$CLASSI_FIN=="SRAG",]$acumobito), colour = "gold4")+
  annotate("text", x = data_se5[data_se5$CLASSI_FIN=="SRAG-não",]$SEM_PRI, y=data_se5[data_se5$CLASSI_FIN=="SRAG-não",]$acumobito/2-15, 
           vjust = -.8, label = data_se5[data_se5$CLASSI_FIN=="SRAG-não",]$acumobito, colour = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:25,labels = labelss) + 
  scale_colour_manual("",values= c("Número de internações acumuladas" = "gold"))+
  scale_fill_manual("","Número de internações acumuladas", values = c("gold","dodgerblue3"))+
  labs(x="Semana Epidemiológica")+ylab("") + theme_bw(base_size = 20)+ylab(NULL)+ylim(-15, max(data_se5$acumtotal)+10)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal",axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

And here I paint with red the parts that I'd like to exclude.
[image]

Any hint on how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `ggplot2` expands the axis for continuous scales by 5 percent on each side and by 0.6 units on each side for discrete scales. To remove or reduce the expansion you can use the expand argument in the scale like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Default
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

```r
# Remove expansion
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use this, them I got the following error: `Error in expansion(mult = c(0, 0)) : could not find function "expansion"`

Comment: @Ga13 Hm. `expansion` was introduced with ggplot2 3.3.0. Maybe you have to update? Before it was `expand_scale`

Comment: Alternatively you could also simply set `expand = c(0,0)` for the same effect.